# Waiting time in Poisson process

Tags: proof-verification, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Let $\{X(t) : t \geq 0\}$ be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$, and let $W_n$ denote the waiting time for the $n$-th event. For $s \geq 0$, determine $P( W_{X(t)} \leq t+s)$ and $P( W_{X(t)+2} \leq t+s)$.

Here's what I've tried.

For $W_{X(t)}$ to be less than $t+s$, the $X(t)$-th event must occur before time $t+s$. This implies that at least $X(t)$ many events must occur before time $t+s$, so we have 
$$
    P( W_{X(t)} \leq t+s) 
    = P( X(t+s) \geq X(t)) 
    = P( X(t+s) - X(t) \geq 0)
    = 1.
$$
Applying similar logic to the second one, 
\begin{align*}
    P(W_{X(t)+2} \leq t + s) 
    &= P(X(t+s) \geq X(t) + 2) \\
    &= 1 - P(X(t+s) - X(t) < 2) \\
    &= 1 - P(X(t+s) - X(t) = 0) - P(X(t+s) - X(t) = 1) \\ 
    &= 1 - e^{-\lambda t} - \lambda t e^{-\lambda t}.
\end{align*}
Is what I've done ok? I'm getting the niggling feeling that I should be using the uniform distribution somehow. Please advise, thanks!

Comment: Frankly, my understanding of poisson processes is really weak. Have I understood $W_{X(t)}$ correctly? I've only ever encountered things like $W_2$ and $W_n$ so I'm really at a loss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much discussion with another student, we've determined that what I did is correct except for a typo in the last line. The answer is 
$$
    P(W_{X(t)+2} \leq t + s)
    = 1 - e^{-\lambda s} - \lambda s e^{-\lambda s}.
$$
Rather than focusing on the Poisson process on its own, it's better to think of things as a renewal process and consider the special case of Poisson processes.

Comment: As you pointed out earlier, $P(W_{X(t) + 2} \leq t+s)  = P(X(t+s) \geq X(t) + 2) = P(X(t+s) -X(t) \geq  2)$. 
Since the process is Poisson, you can write $P(W_{X(t) + 2} \leq t+s)  = P(X(s) - X(0)  \geq 2$. 
Note that the last statement is not true for a renewal process, except for the special case of the Poisson process.
For a renewal process $X(t)$ counts the number of renewal events till time $t$ (including events if any at time t), 
so at time $t$, $W_{X(t)}$ tells you the last renewal epoch before time $t$ (again we account for renewals at $t$ if any).